# What does “magic tests” mean for the file command?

Tags: terminology, file-format, file-command

I was reading about the `file` command and I came across something I don't quite understand:

> file is designed to determine the kind of file being queried.... file
>   accomplishes this by performing **three** sets of tests on the file in
>   question:
>
> - filesystem tests,
> - **magic** tests,
> - language tests

What are **magic** tests?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That refers to the "magic bytes" which many file formats have at the beginning of a file which show what kind of file this is.

E.g. if a file starts with `#!` then it is considered a script.

Answer (score 29):

"magic" here refers to "[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)": a special value that's in a known place in a file that identifies its type. The `file` command has a database of these numbers and what type they correspond to. The library that goes with that database is called [libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic), and you can access that from your own programs.

They aren't necessarily "numbers" as we might think of them. For example, a PNG image file always starts with "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n", a Java class begins with the four bytes (in hexadecimal) CA FE BA BE, and an HTML file has "< html" somewhere near the start. It's just some small sequence of data that's known to be in a file of that type, usually very close to the start.

When people are defining file formats they often include one of these in it either deliberately or just as part of making the format fit together. `file` can use them afterwards. It also has other ways of actually looking at the contents of the file to guess what it is ("language tests").

Comment: Note that originally, the "magic numbers" were, specifically, the first two bytes of an executable file, used by the kernel to load it in the appropriate way. `#!` is actually an example of this, because the kernel itself, on seeing those bytes, is supposed to invoke the command that follows.