# Finding a file type assuming wrong extension

Tags: files, command, utilities, mime-types, file-command

I have an image archive I keep up. Sometimes, the sites I pull them from reformat the file while keeping the extension the same, most often making PNG images into JPG's that are still named ".png".  Is there a way to discover when this has happened and fix it automatically?

When on Windows, I used IrfanView for this, but that needs a Wine wrapper.

Comment: You can use free online tool [Falstaff](http://ec2-54-148-254-76.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/falstaff/ "Falstaff")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `file` command:

```
$ file file.png
file.png: PNG image data, 734 x 73, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced

$ mv file.png file.txt
$ file file.txt
file.txt: PNG image data, 734 x 73, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

The `file` does some tests on file to determine its type. Probably the most important test is comparing a magic number (string in a file header) with pre-defined list.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: When using `file` be aware that it can give differing output across the various Unixes. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151008/linux-file-command-classifying-files/

Comment: On Ubuntu I get the error message: `-bash: file: command not found`. So we need to install the package first (I thought it comes with the default installation). You need to install "file" by `sudo apt install file`

Comment: Tipp: Use `file --mime-type` if you only want the MIME type itself without encoding information, e.g. `application/pdf`. Pass the option `-b` if you don't want to display the file name at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 5):

You can try imagemagicks identify command: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

Example:

```
$ identify rose.jpg
rose.jpg JPEG 640x480 sRGB 87kb 0.050u 0:01
```